Packaging runtime configs with pre-generated MSI
I'm working on packaging my application however after trying several options over the last few months, none feel very nice.
My application concists of two main components, a .NET based web service which will be self hosted on a Linux machine within a customers organisation and an .NET agent which needs to be deployed to various workstations around the organisation.
The agent will communicate with the web service and therefore needs to know its IP/hostname and its self generated certificate's public key (I'm using MTLS GRPC and while I could request the certificate from the server on first run, I'd rather avoid any unencrypted communication if possible).
All customers will receive the same agent installer (I assume theres no way to generate an installer from from a linux machine so I could generate one at runtime?).
My problem is, how do I get the IP and certificate to the agent in the first place?
Ideal Scenario
In a perfect world, I would like my customers to be able to download an installer for the agent from their instance of the web service and have that installer contain all the information required for a secure install (i.e. it should contain the servers hostname, certificate details etc)
Option 1 - Manual MSI parameters/text field
My original approach was to have customers enter the servers IP in a custom step of my MSI (or pass it via msiexec). This worked but is less than ideal given I also require a certificate which is pretty clunky to copy around. The problem only gets worse the more I want to include.
Option 2 - PowerShell
One option I've seen other products use is providing a basic PowerShell script that handles the installation (i.e. download the installer from a remote host, then execute the installer, passing in any required params on the command line). I don't believe this will work for me as the server I'd be communicating with will be using a self signed certificate so I'm back having to trust an unverified initial connection. I could embed the certificate in the PowerShell script to work around this bit again, not the nicest option.
EDIT: Other products implementation of this is 3 lines of powershell (download, extract and execute with required args) which can be easily copied and pasted into PS. In my case, I'd also need to include an encoded self signed certificate and powershell code to add a custom certificate validation callback to use it which is a bit much for a copy/paste job, I'd now need to provide a downloadable PowerShell script. Its an option, just not as nice as a one click installer which is what I was aiming for
Option 3 - MSI editing
Using several MSI tools on Linux I have been able to edit my MSI to prefill fields. This works really well and is my current approach but it has the downside that my service installation needs include 3rd party MSI editing software.
Is there a better option to the above which would allow add values that are only known at time of download into a pregenerated MSI? Is MSI the wrong approach altogether?
Thanks for any help/ideas you can provide

So the main MSI installer for the agent is created in your Windows development environment using - which tools exactly? WiX? And the 3rd party MSI tools for Linux are which ones? These?

Moreover, what is your issue with option #2 - you wrote "I could embed the certificate in the PowerShell script to work around this bit again, not the nicest option." - why exactly is this not "nice" in your eyes?

Hey, yep, my MSI is built with Wix on windows and edited with msitools on linux. I've edited the question with why option 2 isn't preferred

I did not try this out, but according to this SO answer it should be possible to cross-compile a .Net Core project on Linux for Windows. Hence, instead of a PowerShell script. you may be able to set up a small C# project with the standard MSI as embedded resource, plus the certificate file plus a file with the hostnname also as embedded resources and compile it into a single exe file.  This file, when run on Windows, can do all the heavy lifting - unpack all the embedded resources into a temp directory, run MSIEXEC and configure the client.

... of course. you need the .Net SDK installed on the customer's Linux machine, but I guess it is not so much of a problem, since you already running a .Net based service on it.

I had concidered that but it requires either the client to have .NET core installed to run the installer, or I have to bundle the installer which can get up there in size. That being said, I'll give this a try in the morning and see just how large the installer would be

In the past, making self-contained executables with the .Net core runtime enlargened the files by roughly 150MB. Not sure if this is still true today.

StackOverflow duplicate without a good answer

While this question is of great personal interest to me, I think it is off-topic for SE. There are multiple unsatisfactory answers on SO too.

what about a self extracting zip? you can make these in linux and get it to run the installer after extracting

A dotnet wrapper around msiexec looked promising and on windows, with the ahead of time compile option enabled produced a 1.2mb binary, unfortunatelly you cant cross compile AOT binaries so not an option from linux. The best I can do is a self contained .NET app which comes out at 12mb which is a bit much for a bootstrap app

I'm not sure about self extracting zips, from what I can see, to build one on linux will require wine which I'd prefer to avoid.

@Darc: 12mb won't probably bother anyone but you.

... still I think the main issue here is to know what your Linux server environment can provide, and how much influence you have on this. Your former comments make this much of a moving target. Do you have several customers to support, or just a few where you can define your requirements? What about a dockerized environment where you just provide a docker image with all the tools you need? .NET runtime is obviously required, .Net SDK: unclear, you did not reveal this. Are "msitools" really a problem when coming in a docker image? Same for Wine?

At the moment, my only required software is the .NET runtime and nginx. My plan is to deploy everything as a docker package so you're right, a few extra packages isnt the end of the world. 12mb isn the end of the world but its also not great when it doubles the size of the installer.
I'm currently leaning towards the PowerShell options again and am testing it now. I've worked around my main concern of having to embded a large certificate by just embedding and validating the remote server certificates thumbprint which cuts down on the script size significantly. So far its looking promising

@Darc: I think you may post this as answer to your own question.

Thankyou to everyone for their ideas on solving this issue. I've tried a number of the suggested solutions compaired their strengths and weaknesses including complexity to implement, requirement of additional software and size of final output. After all of this, I have settled on my original option 2, with some modifications to reduce complexity.
My primary concern with option 2 when asking my question was around my app relying on self signed certificates, and therefore requiring a public key to be embedded in the script, making it significantly larger.
To work around this issue, I've opted to instead embed the thumbprint of the expected server certificate which significantly reduces the size of the overall script.
Thankyou again to everyone for their input

There is perhaps an obvious solution you have overlooked. Host a public website which all deployments register with and clients connect to to get their config.
So when you spin up your self hosting linux api, the first thing it does it contact www.darc.com and says "hey i am running on machine x with this config"
When you run a client installer, it calls www.darc.com and says "hey have any servers registered from my ip address? send me the list to choose from"
If you want it more secure you would have to add some sort of login, presumably the clients would be ok with prompting for company name/licence code or something which will be the same for all installs.
Also, I assume you have looked into network discovery? have the service listen for  broadcast messages and reply?

I doubt this works for an on-premise server behind a companies firewall blocking any direct public internet access. Moreover, even when the server is allowed to contact the public internet, how can a client automatically identify the correct server from their company? And the broadcast option: that will most probably fail as soon as the client and the server are not in the same subnet.

it's not going to work in a locked down environment no, but I think that begs the question of how even the server is supposed to know the dns entry its exposed on without manual input

Yeah, a public server is not an option and is just shifting the problem, instead of embedding ips/hostnames in the installer your now embedding an identifier to look something up publicly.

the advantage is the embedded lookup is always constant

@Darc what about broadcast to discover the server? is that not an option for you?

Have you considered option 4.
Let the server side generate a client_configuration file containing the IP address and the certificate.
In the client MSI, ask the user to provide (the location of) the client_configuration file. You might even provide a sensible default location. It would be up to your customer's administrator to ensure this file is handled in a secure way.
I would make the client_configuration a text-based file, so that the customer's administrator can make edits to account for, for example, a load balancer or a policy that client software can only be configured with a hostname.

So rather than have them enter the remote IP in the MSI, have them enter the path to a config file? If theres a way to make an MSI file load a file from the same location as the MSI then I might concider that

@Darc, if the MSI cannot do it, make it part of the client app itself. On startup, look for a configuration file at a well-known location. If it isn't there, ask the user for one, copy that to the well-known location and redo the startup logic.

Having to manually specify a config location/manually copy a file to a certain location is the main thing I want to avoid and is why I want to bundle these values into my installer. Also, the client app is a headless service so asking for a config at runtime would involve writing errors to a log file until someone notices the client hasnt checked in yet and corrects the issue

@Darc, with a headless service, you should disregard my previous comment. I was assuming the client would have some form of UI.
